# Apache POI-HSSF: Getting Decimal Instead of Text String

Tags: apache, text, decimal, apache-poi, poi-hssf

I am using Apache POI-HSSF for working with Excel files.

I have a cell in my spreadsheet that looks like "115". I verified that it is formatted as "Text" (Format Cells -> Text).

However, when I read it in as
    row.getCell(0).toString()

I get this string: "115.0"

This is incorrect. I should be getting "115" since it's explicitly formatted as Text. How can I get the desired result? The cell can be anything, numbers or characters, and I expect the same string as in the cell. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatted as text does not mean stored as text, they're different. Excel has stored your cell as a number, and when you ask POI for the cell you get a numeric cell back.

If you ask the cell you get back what type it is, you'll discover it's of type CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC and not CELL_TYPE_STRING

What you'll likely want to do is use the [DataFormatter class](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) to have your cell formatted as per Excel. It'll then look like you expect. (As will cells formatted as currency, percentages etc too)

Answer (score 2):

You should be calling the HSSFCell.getCellType() method to determine its type. Here's a method that handles cells of type String or Numeric. (You can easily add other types.) The format used for numbers will be a valid format, but won't necessarily match that of the SpreadSheet. (That's covered below.)

```
public static String getCellStringValue(final HSSFCell cell) {
    int cellType = cell.getCellType();
    String value;
    if (cellType == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
        // Locale is optional here
        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(Locale.US);
        value = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
    } else {
        // HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING
        value = cell.getStringCellValue();
    } // more cell types are possible. Add whatever you need.
    return value;
}
```

That code won't necessarily format the number as it appears in Excel. 
If you need the format to exactly match the spreadsheet format, you can get a formatter from the cell itself. To do this, you can use your DataFormatter instance to create a Format instance:

```
public static String getCellStringValue(final HSSFCell cell) {
    int cellType = cell.getCellType();
    String value;
    if (cellType == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
        // Locale is optional here
        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(Locale.US);
        Format format = dataFormatter.createFormat(cell);
        value = format.format(cell.getNumericCellValue());
    } else {
        // HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING
        value = cell.getStringCellValue();
    } // more cell types are possible. Add whatever you need.
    return value;
}
```